# Can i place my adBanner to be fixed at the bottom of my screen along side the Bottom Navigation?

Tags: react-native, admob, google-ads-api, react-native-firebase

Can I place my ad banner in the bottom of my screen to be fixed even when scrolled alongside the Bottom navigation
[image: image of example]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your bottom footer is having height=80

To place it on the position above your bottom footer, you may:

```
<View style={{position: 'absolute', height:100, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 80}}>

<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <Text> Nice Job !</Text>
</View>

</View>
```

i.e. Use position: 'absolute' and bottom: 80 [height of the footer]